# What are the differences between AWS EC2 t1 and t2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I try to create a new EC2 instance, there are many instance types to select from: t1.micro, t2.nano, t2.micro, etc.

To understand the differences between t1, t2, t3, etc. I go to https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ but the documentation here has no mention of T1.

What are the differences between t1 and t2 instances?

Comment: AWS regularly gets better hardware over the years. T1, T2, T3, T4 correspond to these hardware updates; you're never better off using an older one. Use the most recent generation; they're faster and either cheaper or the same price.

Answer (score 0):

You can count t2 as upgrade of t1. In general t2 offer faster access to memory and disk compared to t1. For more information you can check [this link](https://faun.pub/aws-ec2-instances-comparison-using-sysbench-t1-vs-t2-vs-t3-vs-t3a-vs-t4g-9540a221d563).

And [currently](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html) t1 type instances are not available.

Answer (score 0):

There's a different physical hardware underneath too.

For example t2 uses "Up to 3.3 GHz Intel Xeon Scalable processor (Haswell E5-2676 v3 or Broadwell E5-2686 v4)", while t3 uses "Up to 3.1 GHz Intel Xeon Scalable processor (Skylake 8175M or Cascade Lake 8259CL)" and t3a "AMD EPYC 7000 series processors (AMD EPYC 7571) with an all core turbo clock speed of 2.5 GHz"

you can find the full details at https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ or search for the tech specs.

Comment: The link you have in your post is exactly the link I shared in my question. I do not see any mention of t1 in that link and that is why I asked this question.

Comment: You're right. But T1 instances are no longer available. They are replaced by t2 and other members of the T family. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/previous-generation/